# SDL2 Window Retains Focus when VSCode Debugger Triggers inside SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN Response

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-code, sdl-2, vscode-debugger

I am in Ubuntu, writing C++, and using SLD2 in vscode. I am normally able to use the debugger just fine.

I have been running into issues where, if I set a breakpoint in code that runs during my SDL_PollEvent loop, and particularly when said breakpoint is triggered due to an event of type SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN, then vscode triggers but the SDL2 window still has focus. This means I cannot click on anything. I can type, and in order to use another window I have to use hotkeys like Alt+Tab to get to a terminal and forcibly kill my SDL2 program.

This does not happen when I have breakpoints in other locations, including SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP, outside of my event polling loop, etc.

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post.